# add schema name as prefix of table name when use scaffold

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

In my SQL server database, I have two schemas `dbo` and `process` and in each schema, I have a table named `product`.
When using `scaffold` in visual studio (using flag `-Schemas "dbo", "process"`), there are entities `product` and `product1`.
This is not a perfect default name (in my opinion of course).
**Is there a way to set naming strategies for this scenario in `scaffold` command?** (like using schema name as a prefix)

Comment: You can have same named classes as long as they're in different namespaces. Have you tried `scaffold --schema dbo --namespace MyContext.dbo` and `scaffold --schema process --namespace MyContext.process`?

Comment: I am using scaffold command in Visual Studio like this `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=myDb;User Id=sa;Password=123456;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DbModels -Context DataContext -Schema "dbo" -Namespace "dbo" -Schema "process" -Namespace "process" -NoPluralize -force`  and I get this error `Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Schemas' is specified more than once`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning when I use one -Schema it will break again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this worked for me

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Initial Catalog=myDb;;Persist Security Info=False;User Id=sa;Password=123456;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Context DataContext   -Tables "dbo.Process" -Force